# Parsing a vCard file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vcf-vcard

I want to retrieve the data from a .vcf file. It is in vcf format.

I need the regular expression formula for each item of data mentioned below. I tried but could not make it work.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:s James F ' Ernande.
ADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=280,43,54,269,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;P.O. Box No: 570, P. C-112, Ruwi Muscat, Sultanate Ofoman;;;;
X-IS-TAKE-ADR;CHARSET=utf-8:23.62866567746918;58.26649072858852;
N;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=33,89,29,178;CHARSET=utf-8:s;James F ' Ernande. ;;;
EMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=116,59,26,237;CHARSET=utf-8:james@om.bluerhine.com
EMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=142,61,26,234;CHARSET=utf-8:oman@onn.bluerhine.com
EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-16
EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-16
AUTHOR:IntSig-iOS-iPhone
ORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=0,0,0,0,59,29,33,295,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;Business Development Manaus)r;
TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=88,107,23,142;CHARSET=utf-8:+96897641700
TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=332,133,28,182;CHARSET=utf-8:+96822022247
TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=328,36,27,92;CHARSET=utf-8:24796647
END:VCARD
```

Code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<strElement>(FN))   (:(?<strFN>[^\r\n]*))", options);// For retrieving the First Name
Regex regex = new Regex(@"((?<strElement>(EMAIL)) (;*(?<strAttr>(HOME|WORK)))*  (;(?<strPref>(PREF)))* (;[^:]*)*  (:(?<strValue>[^\n\r]*)))");//for retrieving Email
```

I am not getting the exact regular expression formula required.

Comment: Use an existing vcard parser rather than trying to write your own - there's at least three on NuGet. You can probably hack something together out of regexs but it'll be easier to use already-tested code that already handles the character sets and escaping properly.

Comment: Regex isn't for every string parsing.  You need to parse each line by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple parser :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication124
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "BEGIN:VCARD\n" +
                "VERSION:2.1\n" +
                "FN;CHARSET=utf-8:s James F ' Ernande.\n" +
                "ADR;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=280,43,54,269,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;;P.O. Box No: 570, P. C-112, Ruwi Muscat, Sultanate Ofoman;;;;\n" +
                "X-IS-TAKE-ADR;CHARSET=utf-8:23.62866567746918;58.26649072858852;\n" +
                "N;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=33,89,29,178;CHARSET=utf-8:s;James F ' Ernande. ;;;\n" +
                "EMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=116,59,26,237;CHARSET=utf-8:james@om.bluerhine.com\n" +
                "EMAIL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=142,61,26,234;CHARSET=utf-8:oman@onn.bluerhine.com\n" +
                "EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-16\n" +
                "EXCHANGEDATE:2019-06-16\n" +
                "AUTHOR:IntSig-iOS-iPhone\n" +
                "ORG;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=0,0,0,0,59,29,33,295,0,0,0,0;CHARSET=utf-8:;Business Development Manaus)r;\n" +
                "TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=88,107,23,142;CHARSET=utf-8:+96897641700\n" +
                "TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=332,133,28,182;CHARSET=utf-8:+96822022247\n" +
                "TEL;WORK;X-EDIT=0;X-POS=328,36,27,92;CHARSET=utf-8:24796647\n" +
                "END:VCARD";


            ParseVCF parseVCF =  new ParseVCF(input);
        }

    }

    public class ParseVCF
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public List<string> data = new List<string>();
        enum State
        {
            FIND_BEGIN,
            GET_VERSION,
            PROCESS_DATA,
            FOUND_END
        }

        public ParseVCF(string input)
        {

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            string line = "";
            State state = State.FIND_BEGIN;
            while(((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) && (state != State.FOUND_END))
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_BEGIN :
                            if (line.StartsWith("BEGIN:"))
                            {
                                state = State.GET_VERSION;
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.GET_VERSION :
                            string[] split = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                            version = split[1];

                            state = State.PROCESS_DATA;
                            break;
                        case State.PROCESS_DATA :
                            if(line.StartsWith("END"))
                            {
                                state = State.FOUND_END;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.Add(line);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how this actually helps with the specific requirement. How would someone use this class to find the requested data? All it seems to do is read the lines of the file into an array of strings. That's not really what I would call parsing. Parsing usually involves assigning some actual meaning to the data, not just putting the raw strings into a list. The only value which seems to actually get parsed into an identifiable property is the version. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the rest remains unprocessed.

Comment: Yes they did specify what they wanted. Admittedly it's buried in code comments at the end of each regex line but it does say "retrieving the First Name" and "retrieving the email"